# SAS epoch to datetime conversion in R

Tags: r

I am reading a very high volume sas7bdat file in R and converting it into a dataframe. However, one of the fields is a SAS Epoch date. Any idea how I can convert this to a datetime field?

I know in SQL Server, we can convert using: `DATEADD(ss, myDate, '19600101')`

Any way we can do the same in R?

Answer (score -1):

Following [Zheyuan Li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4891738/zheyuan-li)'s comment,

```
as.Date(myDate, origin = "1960-01-01")
```

should do the trick.